# Servlet Mapping With Wildcards

Tags: wildcard, web.xml, servlet-mapping

I'm having trouble with the servlet mapping in web.xml. It works when I put in a specific file but not when using a wildcard:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources123/bootstrap.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works fine. But when I change the URL pattern to /resources123/* it doesn't hit the DispatcherServlet.